# October / Wintercms : set default list filter values programatically

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm using Wintercms (fork of Octobercms) to create a backend application which needs to display some data according to a date range.

I've used the list filters to be able to select custom date range: https://wintercms.com/docs/backend/lists#list-filters

But when we land on the list, I would like to have a **default date range selected**.
The rule would be: "From 1st of february to 31st of october of the current year":

[image]

I haven't found any way of doing so in the documentations nor in internet examples..

Comment: there is a `default` option you can set values there, for date ref: https://wintercms.com/docs/backend/lists#filter-daterange

Comment: Yes but not dynamically according to current year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate dynamic defaults by adding scope definition in `ListFilterExtendScopes` event: https://wintercms.com/docs/backend/lists#extend-filter-scopes

Default for daterange scope is array of :afterDate and :beforeDate values:

```
        $filter->addScopes([
            'latest' => [
                'label' => 'Latest',
                'type'  => 'daterange',
                'conditions' => 'latest >= \':afterDate\' AND latest <= \':beforeDate\'',
                'yearRange'  => '20',
                'default'    => [
                    0: Carbon::now()->subDays(10),
                    1: Carbon::now()->addDays(10),
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: That's roughly what I ended up doing ! Thanks ! :)